# Развертывание сайта на asp.net

Tags: база-данных, asp.net

Здравствуйте, я написал сайт на asp.net, к которому также подключена база данных SQL.

Я развернул сайт с помощью IIS, но работают только те страницы сайта, на которых не задействована БД. Как мне можно расшарить эту базу, чтобы эти страницы открывались?

P.S. диплом сдавать скоро, а я даже открыть сайт нормально не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: в текущей Вашей постановке вопроса Вам будет очень сложно помочь. Вы бы добавили конкретики: сайт написан на чистом `asp.net` или с использованием `mvc`, каким образом Вы работает с бд(`ado`|`orm`), какая бд у Вас используется(`mssql`,`mysql`,...), что происходит на тех страницах на которых *задействована* бд, если `exception` то добавьте его в исходный вопрос.

Comment: Сайт написан на asp.net с использованием MVC.

Comment: Сайт написан на asp.net с использованием MVC.

Используется Microsoft SQL server, а работаю с ней с на страницах при помощи Entity Framework(если я правильно понял). Делал я по примеру с сайта http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level2/2_1.php

На тех страницах, на которых задействована БД вылазит вот такая ошибка: http://joxi.ru/Dr8KE4Rtk0qyBA

Comment: внесите соответствующие изменения в исходный вопрос при помощи кнопки [edit], текст исключение вставьте текстом а не картинкой, при обращении к пользователю не забывайте писать символ `@` перед ником пользователя(тогда придет нотификация). а по существу у Вас нет соединения с бд. добавьте в исходный вопрос строку соединения

Comment: @Bald Вот текст мой connection string, который находится в Web.config:

<connectionStrings>  

    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Store;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  

  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @Bald Текст ошибки: Server Error in '/' Application. 

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)

Comment: @Bald Я обнаружил, что при смене connection string на неправильный и попытке запуска сайта при помощи Visual Studio, работают тоже только те страницы, на которых нету работы с БД, а при попытке перейти на страницу, содержащую БД, Visual Studio выдаёт ошибку, практически идентичную той, что я получаю на установленном с помощью IIS сайте. Т.е. ошибка с сайтом, который я разместил с помощью IIS, скорее всего, связана с connection string, но я не могу понять как её изменить.

Comment: при публикации приложения на сервере перенесли ли Вы локальную бд. ошибка связана с тем что Ваше приложение не может подключиться к бд, отсюда и ошибка. копайте в эту сторону